# How to hide element in ListView in databinding for specific value

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have XML file and listView and I want to hide specific XAML element in this list View Item if value of XML element `<Finished>` equals false.

How can I do it?

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: bind the isVisible property to a property which exposes visible or collapsed based on the xml element value

Comment: thanks for answer but what if value of XML element is not true or false for example value can be datetime or null. How can I solve this?

Comment: What would you want to happen in such case?

Comment: if value is null then I need to hide some element by visibility=collapsed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bind the XAML element's visibility to the `Finished` property of the list item.

You will need to bind it through a converter that takes a boolean value and returns `Visibility.Visible` or `Visibility.Collapsed` as appropriate:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Finished,
                        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

The converter:

```
public class GenderConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
            return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If the value isn't a boolean the converter will be slightly more complex and you may need to pass in a `ConverterParameter` as a control value so you can have more control over when you return `Visibility.Visible`

Comment: @ChrisF I know this is an old one, but I'm having a problem with this solution. It hides the item, but the space it would use remains the same. Do you have any idea how to get passed this?

Comment: @Meneses it might be other elements on the page claiming the space. Post a new question with **all** your code and include a reference to this answer explaining where you got the code from.

Comment: It was the ItemContainerStyle. It had elements that were taking a minimum amount of space. I changed it and it worked fine.